# returning a an alphabetically sorted list of animals whose last letter does not end any letters listed in the argument

Tags: java, list, collections

I need to create a method that returns an alphabetic list of animals that don't end in any of the letters in the argument array. There should also be no duplicates in the returned list

```
public class TrimmList
{

private List<String> inList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("aardvark", 
"cow", "dog", "cow",
"elephant","dog", "frog", "bird", "swan", "python", "pig"));

public List<String> trimList(char[] args)
{
Set<String> toRemove = new HashSet<>();
for (String a : arr) {
for (String i : inList) {
if (i.endsWith(a)) {
toRemove.add(i);
}
inList.removeAll(toRemove);
}
}
System.out.println(inList);
 // [bird, aardvark, cow, elephant]
}
```

So if one of the letters in the argument is 'g' for example, pig shouldn't be returned

Any advice much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better you use a `TreeSet` so that strings will automatically be sorted alphabetically. Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class AddToArrayList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        List<String> inList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("aardvark", "cow", "dog", "cow", "elephant", "dog",
                "frog", "bird", "swan", "python", "pig"));
        System.out.println(trimList(new char[] { 'g', 'n' }, inList));
    }

    static List<String> trimList(char[] args, List<String> inList) {
        Set<String> result = new TreeSet<String>();
        boolean found;
        for (String s : inList) {
            found = false;
            for (char ch : args) {
                if (s.endsWith(String.valueOf(ch))) {
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                result.add(s);
            }
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(result);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[aardvark, bird, cow, elephant]
```

Note when a string from the list is added to the set. A string from the list needs to be added to the set only after all characters in `args[]` have been compared.

Comment: thanks so much.though from where I have began my class and then opened my method, nothing much change in between those two

Comment: I didn't get you. Do you find anything missing in this answer?

Comment: its ok - i figured it. Thanks so much for the help, it's much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have less lambda expressions you can also use this snippet.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class TrimList {

    private List<String> inList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("aardvark", "cow", "dog", "cow",
            "elephant", "dog", "frog", "bird", "swan", "python", "pig"));

    public List<String> trimList(char[] args) {

        inList = new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(inList));
        List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String animal : inList) {
            for (char c : args) {
                if (animal.endsWith(String.valueOf(c))) {
                    temp.add(animal);
                }
            }
        }
        inList.removeAll(temp);
        Collections.sort(inList);
        System.out.println(inList);
        return inList;
    }
}
```

Output will be

```
[aardvark, bird, cow, elephant, python, swan]
```

Comment: thank you so much! I need to complete it one method though, public List<String> trimList(char[] args) < that is the opening of my method, i will be inserting my own chars when testing so i can't really add any examples within the code..

Comment: Ok, so do you need further help?

Comment: hmmm. Better but I'm a little confused. Sorry I'm so new to coding so I'm trying my best to understand. So everything must be inside the trimList method I have stated, I don't think I should add 'main' method you specified as i will be inserting different chars each time of testing, have you got any advice?

Comment: thanks for taking your time to advise, much appreciated

Comment: great. thanks so much, i just have one extra problem! there should be no duplicates returned in the collect, so when i test - cow can appear twice, how could i fix this?

Comment: dog can appear twice aswell

Comment: sry didnt read that ive added the duplicate remove with a inList = new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(inList));